# How to solve permission denied error in cron?

Tags: python, shell, cron

I am trying to run a shell script file using cron and I am getting permission denied error.

Here is my cron file.

```
53 14 30 10 * $HOME/Documents/Python/shellScript.sh
```

I want to run shellScript file at a particular time today.

Here is my shellScript.sh file.

```
osascript<<EOF
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
end
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script with command "python file1.py" in window 1
end tell
EOF

osascript<<EOF
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
end
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script with command "./ngrok 5000" in window 1
end tell
EOF

python file2.py
```

I am getting this in the mail.
/bin/sh: /Users/XXX/Documents/Python/shellScript.sh: Permission denied

It would be great if anyone can help me with this. 
Thank you

Comment: post the output of `ls -l shellScript.sh`. Please edit the output into your post

Comment: you must give execute permission to your script before executing. `chmod u+x shellScript.sh`

Comment: @Hackaholic Yes It worked. If you can post your answer in answers then I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you must give execute permission to your script before executing.

```
chmod u+x shellScript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are invoking `osascript` and a Terminal at all - OSX's `crond` is perfectly able to run scripts itself.

You should be able to just do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /path/to/file1.py &
ngrok 5000 &
python /path/to/file2.py
```

and be sure to make the above executable with

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/shellScript.sh
```